# How to prevent a Linux C++ library from crashing on an out-of-bounds read?

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I am using a closed-source 3rd party Linux lib (.so) compiled for an older version of Linux on an older version of gcc.

Unfortunately, it crashes occasionally with a read of an invalid memory address.

This is certainly undesirable, and it would be fantastic to fix the library. But as that is absolutely impossible, and it still functions perfectly well on older versions of Linux, is there some way to avoid the crash, and simply restart the app every day?

It's either that or attempt to run it on an extremely old version of Linux that apparently ignores such errors.

---

### Update 2020-07-09

Everything is working reliably now, see my answer below. Sometimes the act of posing a question in a succinct way leads to finding the correct answer.

Comment: "_and it still functions properly_" Technically, if it would function properly - you wouldn't have this question :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, I don't like the situation. But apparently it does function perfectly well on older versions of Linux that do not have have a "crash on invalid reads" switched on. So it's about trying to make the best tradeoff - it comes down to a choice between no data loss, or complete data loss.

Comment: can you controll start address in memory for loading this library ? maybe by special lcf file when you get linked with it

Comment: the likely reason is also that lib is compiled wit rather old version of runtime and if it's C++  you _can't use newer C++ standard than that library_ in your program, because you're running in UBs across whole assembly due to ODR breach. GCC is backward compatible only if you maintain same language standard

Comment: It depends where the incompatibility lies. Have you any idea? I suppose it *may* be possible to compile a wrapper library around it, using the old system compiler, and have the wrapper library present a binary compatible interface (like exchanging serialized text rather than numbers and/or structs) but it will depend on where the incompatibility lies.

Comment: What if you set a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: @Contango That cannot be switched off. Something caused it to *not* read out of bounds on previous versions of Linux.

Comment: @Swift That makes sense - I'm compiling it for C++17, and it was originally compiled for something far earlier than that. Wonder if this implies any solutions?

Comment: @Contagio , it might, but to answer that a postmortem dump must be  studied for actual reason of out of bound. It might be runtime related or it might be result of some system API changed .. that happens.  Normally .so libraries protected from that by rejecting attempt to load them if they are dependent on incompatible versions of system calls, but closed-source library - it's a fault of developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a closed-source 3rd party Linux lib (.so) compiled for an older version of Linux on an older version of gcc.

Note that neither "older Linux" nor "older gcc" is the *reason* for the crash, a *bug* in the library is. A bug-less library compiled 15 years ago would still work perfectly fine today.

> it would be fantastic to fix the library. But as that is absolutely impossible, and it still functions perfectly well on older versions of Linux, is there some way to avoid the crash, and simply restart the app every day?

In general, you can't "avoid the crash and continue as if nothing happened". But you can attempt to "catch the crash, save state and restart the application" with a `SIGSEGV` signal handler which executes [siglongjmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/siglongjmp.3.html).

This will be more or less reliable depending on the exact *reason* for the crash (which you haven't described).

> It's either that or attempt to run it on an extremely old version of Linux that apparently ignores such errors.

Old Linux did *not* ignore such problems: invalid memory access has *always* generated a crash.

But old Linux (probably) didn't violate the 3rd party developer's *incorrect* assumptions, and new one does, triggering the invalid memory access.

You should try to *understand* what causes the crash (which assumptions are violated). There might be a trivial workaround.

E.g. if the library assumed a process can't have more than 1024 file descriptors, and used [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), you can arrange that the library never observes `fd >= 1024`, by reserving "low" file descriptors for it.

Comment: Everything appears to be working reliably now. Marked this answer as the official one as it is closest to the original question. I added an answer with the solution that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer: I spent 3 months with it failing every day, and 6 days after posting on SO I find the solution.

Whatever the original reason, everything is working reliably now. It was caused by one of the two following issues, I could run some tests to narrow it down to one or the other:

- Compiling with gcc under `Windows x64/WSL v1/Ubuntu` then copying the resultant binary and `.so` files to a remote machine running native Ubuntu. It was the same version of Ubuntu in both cases (`v18.04`).
- An edge router that was limiting the bandwidth to 5MBit/second. It would randomly drop packets if traffic got too high, which caused the 3rd party library to crash due to an internal logic error.